# can anyone explain me the functionality of tools.jar( which is bundled in jdk/lib folder) and why it's required?

Tags: java

I have come across with tools.jar file in java.So,want to know about it that what exactly it is used for?I have search a lot but can't find a doc.
It will really helpful if someone can specify me its details as i am new to java.
Thanks.

Comment: JDK-Java Development Toolkit, tools(javac,javap,javadoc,etc) in Toolkit are in tools.jar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `tools.jar` are all tools that are needed by a JDK but not a JRE.

Included in `tools.jar` is e.g. the compiler `javac` and the tool `javadoc`. All tools needed to develop in Java are included in this `.jar` file.

Comment: javac and javadoc is also provided in bin folder?So again why bundle it in lib folder as tools.jar?Links to actual jls/java doc from oracle/sun would be good.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/jdkfiles.html says "Files used by the development tools. Includes tools.jar, which contains non-core classes for support of the tools and utilities in the JDK. Also includes dt.jar, the DesignTime archive of BeanInfo files that tell interactive development environments (IDE's) how to display the Java components and how to let the developer customize them for an application."

Comment: @nanosoft The tools provided in the `/bin` folder are simple wrapper that call java classes from the `tools.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

tools.jar contains classes used by javac and some java utils which come only with JDK, like javah, javap, jarsigner, javadoc etc

Answer (score 1):

`tools.jar` will give support to your daily-use java commands, e.g. `javac`, `javap`.
It also contains some infrastructures for JMI and applet.

You can use `jar xvf tools.jar` to unjar the package and get some knowledge from the file hierarchy.